# .xauth followed by random numbers

Tags: x11, xauth

According to my own experience, **su - user** used to break SSH X11 authentication. There are plenty of posts on the web explaining how to use **xauth list** and **xauth add** to copy the MIT-COOKIE between sessions.

However, for some reason this is no longer necessary.

When I login using **ssh -X usera@host**, I see the following as usual:

-rw------- 1 usera usera   63 Jul 25 18:17 .Xauthority

When I do **su - userb**, the system automatically creates and uses the following:

-rw------- 1 userb userb    63 Jul 25 18:18 **.xauthpNLBVw**

The new .xauth file contains a copy of the MIT-COOKIE of the previous user, thus allowing me to run X11 apps. It's not necessarily a bad idea, but how is this accomplished. I've tried RHEL 5- 7 and it's the same on all those systems, even though nothing has changed that would explain this new behavior.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is implemented by the `pam_xauth.so` module which you can find documented in `man pam_xauth`. If you look in the last line of `/etc/pam.d/su` you should find a line

```
session         optional        pam_xauth.so
```

which runs the module when you do `su - userb`. In the environment, variable `XAUTHORITY` will be set to the temporary file with the copied cookie. This file is removed at the end of the session.

Interestingly, if `usera` only wants to forward their display cookie to a given set of users, they can be listed in `~usera/.xauth/export`. Similarly, `userb` can list the users it will accept cookies from in `~userb/.xauth/import`.